# How to automatically bill Customer B depending on Customer A's subscription charge on Stripe?

Tags: stripe-payments

We are looking for a way to bill one customer depending on how much another customer is charged weekly using Stripe Subscriptions. So the idea is to offer a weekly gym membership to full-time employees at city offices. The weekly fee will be $20 and we want the employees' company to contribute a certain amount to the weekly fee. For example, Customer A (employee) will pay $16 and Customer B (employee's Company) will pay the remaining $6. Is there a way to take Customer A's charge successful receipt and trigger Customer B's card to be charged automatically? The $20 subscription fee is not fixed as it will change depending on their usage ($20 is for 5 working days. If they use it for 3 days the total charge will be $12).

Answer (score 0):

Since you are controlling Customer A's subscription and charge you can automate all of this. You indicated that you will change how much you charge Customer A each month. This is something that your code will handle and at that point it can automatically charge Customer B's card for the remainder of the fee.

Otherwise, you can use [webhooks](https://stripe.com/docs/webhooks) and listen for `charge.succeeded` events. Whenever Customer A has a successful charge, your webhook handler will find the corresponding Customer B in your database and create a Charge for the correct amount.